# parsing array (json) with PHP foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to write for each for separe the object name and value which is inside 'ques' array.

my array as

```
 [
 {
    "ques": [
        {
            "name": "comment",
            "value": "comment me for the reason",
            "sur_id": "1",
            "user_id": "admin@gmail.com",
            "pagename": "question_response"
        },
        {
            "name": "check-box[]",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "radio",
            "value": "radio 2"
        },
        {
            "name": "yes",
            "value": "no"
        },
        {
            "name": "date",
            "value": "2015-10-23"
        },
        {
            "name": "select-deopdown",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "true",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "name": "number",
            "value": "55"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to separte value form ques array.now 'answer' return null

```
  while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
   $content = $fetch['CONTENT_VALUES'];
  // print_r($content);
  $content_value= mb_convert_encoding($content ,"UTF-8");
    $datas = json_decode($content, true);
     foreach($datas->ques as $values)
     {
         echo $values->value . "\n";
          print_r($values);
     }
   $test[] = array('ques' =>  $datas ,'answer'=>$values);
}
```

Comment: `foreach($datas->ques as $key=>$values)`

Answer (score 2):

You're using `json_decode($content, true);` ([consult the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) so that means you're getting an array back, not an object. Either remove the `true` or treat it as an associative array

```
foreach($datas[0]['ques'] as $values)
```

Comment: tried both suggestion given by you sir.still return null alue

Comment: Tricky. There's an array wrapping the whole thing. So regardless you have to reference element `0`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code to be like this:

```
 while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
 $content = $fetch['CONTENT_VALUES'];
  $content_value= mb_convert_encoding($content ,"UTF-8");
    $datas = json_decode($content); //To return as Object
    foreach($array[0]->ques as $values):
        echo $values->name.'<br/>'; //For example
    endforeach;

}
```

Comment: @user3386779 try again

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your *real* problem is, that you never assign anything to `$test[]` in the loop?

Anyway - you are mixing object and arrays. As mentioned above, remove the `true` param from `json_decode`. The below works for me (hopefully I have understood what the goal is) :

```php
//test load of the JSON
$content = file_get_contents('test.json');

$test = array();
$datas = json_decode($content);
foreach($datas[0]->ques as $item) {
    $test[] = array('ques' => $item->name, 'answer' => $item->value);
}
```

then

```php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '<pre>';
```

outputs

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ques] => comment
            [answer] => comment me for the reason
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ques] => check-box[]
            [answer] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ques] => radio
            [answer] => radio 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ques] => yes
            [answer] => no
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ques] => date
            [answer] => 2015-10-23
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ques] => select-deopdown
            [answer] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ques] => true
            [answer] => false
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ques] => number
            [answer] => 55
        )

)
```